# How to define the type of a button in react / typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm currently trying to define the type of a button component, it's currently set as any so it's working, but what would be the real type of this property ?

```
import React, { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";

interface ButtonI {
  className?: string;
  label?: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  type?: any;
  onClick?: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

const Button: React.FC<ButtonI> = (props) => {
  return (
    <button
      className={`${props.className}`}
      type={props.type || "button"}
      aria-label={props.label || ""}
      onClick={() => (props.onClick ? props.onClick(true) : null)}
    >
      {props.children}
    </button>
  );
};

export default React.memo(Button);
```

Comment: isn't `button` itself a type?

Comment: it's a default value here, what i mean is what if the type of the button is submit ? "submit"  | "button" would do but is it the good way to do it ?

Comment: saw this issue https://github.com/couds/react-bulma-components/issues/230 in this link...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of a button type is

```
React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>["type"]
```

Usage:

```
type?: React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>["type"]
```

it accepts:

```
"button" | "reset" | "submit" | undefined
```